# SIGTRAP -[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm having a `SIGTRAP` problem on my iPhone app with a `-[__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...`

The crash is happening when I call an `UITableView`.

I have no idea how to track this problem, so I'm asking for help.

Does anyone know the reasons why I could be getting a `SIGTRAP` problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably because you calling count on something you think is an array, but is actually a string.

Comment: I'm calling an array, and made sure with NSLog (@"Array %@", [self.names class]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calling `-count` a NSArray method on a NSString variable. Make sure your variable your calling count in is a NSArray or a collection object before calling count.

Comment: I'm calling an array, and made sure with NSLog (@"Array %@", [self.names class]);

Comment: Check in other places, also set your breakpoint to all exceptions to pin point the exact location of your crash.

Comment: I did that and I was handling a malformed array in another place. Thanks!